# Creating subsites in Sharepoint Online on a Site generated by a Teams team

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create a Subsite in Sharepoint Online within a site that was automatically generated via a MS Teams team but the option to do so doesnt exist. 
The option to create Subsite seems to ONLY exist if a Site was created from within Sharepoint Online.

I can understand that a workaround would be to create it as another Site within Sharepoint Online and then link the relevant Sites together under a HUB.
Am I missing something or this feature does not exist in Sharepoint Online unless I create the Subsites as Sites and then link them up via a Hub?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in the SharePoint Online Admin Center to [Hide or Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-creation#manage-detailed-site-and-subsite-creation-settings-in-the-classic-sharepoint-admin-center) the create subsites option.

Microsoft is discouraging the use of subsites, and the creation of subsites is likely to continue to be phased out as more features and capabilities are added to Hubs.  While there are still exceptions to the rule, since there are still aspects that Hubs cannot accomplish (like connecting Hubs together to a parent Hub), you should seriously consider building your solution to use separate site collections.

Depending on how the rest of your SharePoint environment is architected, a better approach would be to setup that team site as a hubsite, then create the additional site collections you need, and link it to the new hubsite. This way you kind of mimic the subsite structure ( but not all its features ) while preserving every site independent.

For more information on best practices on SharePoint site Architecture, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/information-architecture-modern-experience.